# COBOL Syntax error 'unexpected' ( with Display command

Tags: cobol

Hello guys I'm currently learning COBOL and I'm kinda stuck in my exercise.
I'm currently using the german book Insider COBOL to get into the topic.

Now the problem:
I was reconstructing the introduction example, it's a calculator for the gross price, you write the amount of products, the price and the VAT and the programm will give you the net amount, the VAT amount and the gross amount back.

At the end I saw I had a typo earlier in the code so i fixed it.
After that the whole Procedure Division went wild with all my Displays where I create the gui.

Every error says "syntax error, unexpected (" a few say "expecting OMITTED or Identifier" after the syntax error too.
I googled if thesyntax has changed but I don't really get it, whats wrong.

Here is the code:

---

```
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************
   B100.
  ******************************************************************
  *****    Ausgabe Bildkopf
  ******************************************************************
       DISPLAY (1,1) ERASE.                *>Löschen des Bildschirms
       DISPLAY (1,1)
       'B R U T T O P R E I S B E R E C H N U N G            PROG01'
               WITH HIGHLIGHT.
       DISPLAY (2,1) S-Strich.
  ******************************************************************
  *****    Einlesen der Daten 
  ******************************************************************
   B150.
       DISPLAY (3,1) 
           'MENGE..............................:'.
       ACCEPT  (3,40)  E-MENGE.
       DISPLAY (4,1) 
           'EINZELPREIS:.......................:'.
       ACCEPT  (4,40)  E-PREIS.
       DISPLAY (5,1)  
           'MW-ST-PROZENTSATZ..................:'.
       ACCEPT  (5,40) E-MWST.
       DISPLAY (6,1) S-Strich.
  ******************************************************************
  *****    Berechnung
  ******************************************************************
   B200.
       COMPUTE S-NETTO = E-MENGE*E-PREIS.
       COMPUTE
          S-MWST-BETR = S-NETTO*E-MWST/100.
       COMPUTE S-BRUTTO = S-NETTO+S-MWST-BETR.
  ******************************************************************
  *****    Ausgabe der Ergebnisse
  ******************************************************************
   B300.
       MOVE    S-NETTO     TO  A-NETTO.     *>Übertragen in Ausgabe
       DISPLAY (8,1)
           'NETTOWERT:....................:'.
       DISPLAY (8,30) A-NETTO.
       MOVE    S-MWST-BETR TO  A-MWST-BETR.
       DISPLAY (9,1) 
           'MEHRWERTSTEUER:...............:'.
       DISPLAY (9,30)  A-MWST-BETR.
       MOVE    S-BRUTTO    TO  A-BRUTTO.
       DISPLAY (10,1)
           'BRUTTOPREIS:..................:'.
       DISPLAY (10,30) A-BRUTTO.
  ******************************************************************
  *****    Ausgabe Systemzeile
  ******************************************************************
   B400.
       DISPLAY (23,1)  S-Strich    ERASE.
       DISPLAY (24,1)  'WEITERE BERECHNUNGEN (J/N) :'.
       ACCEPT  (24,40) S-WEITER    WITH    AUTO-SKIP.
       IF  S-WEITER    = 'J'   *> es werden nur Großbuchstaben
           GO TO   B100        *> aktzeptiert
       END-IF.
       IF  S-WEITER = 'N'
           GO To B900
       END-IF.
  *****    falsche Eingabe:
       GO TO B400.
```

I hope I'm not blind or something and thank you in advance :)

Comment: What's the actual, full error message?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected (, expecting OMITTED or Identifier
 //and sometimes the expecting... part is missing

Comment: No filename or line number?

Comment: Filename is my Test.cbl and the lines are 56,57 and so on everywhere where the DISPLAY is.

Comment: There is no DISPLAY on line 56 or 57.

Comment: Oh well I didnt say it was just a part of my whole code my bad on my whole Code the first DISPLAYS are line 56, 57, ... if it helps I can comment the whole Code too.

Comment: Please edit your question and supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using `DISPLAY ... AT line col ` would be syntactically correct... `DISPLAY (line,col) ...` is not, therefore the ( is not expected.
Not sure what compiler you use (as far as a quick check with the book title said these are old outdated compilers and may not match with anything you currently use).

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the code and the error message, it looks like you're trying to compile Microsoft COBOL with GnuCOBOL. Sadly, GnuCOBOL <strike>does not (yet)</strike> did not recognize the Microsoft-style position-specifier when this question was asked.

*Update: works completely fine with GC 3.x since 2018, see the comment.*

With an old GnuCOBOL version (or many other compilers) you'll have to manually translate every `DISPLAY` and `ACCEPT` statement to standard COBOL; for instance,

```
 DISPLAY (3,1) 
     'MENGE..............................:'.
 ACCEPT  (3,40)  E-MENGE.
```

becomes

```
 DISPLAY
     'MENGE..............................:'
     AT LINE 3 COL 1
 ACCEPT E-MENGE LINE 3 COL 40.
```

More of a problem is the `ERASE` phrase in `DISPLAY`. The closest option GnuCOBOL <strike>has</strike> had to that is the Micro Focus' `DISPLAY SPACES` extension. To use it, change, for example,

```
   DISPLAY (23,1)  S-Strich    ERASE.
```

to

```
   DISPLAY S-Strict LINE 23 COL 1, SPACES
```

Comment: Just a note: GnuCOBOL 3.0rc2 (to be released) features support for Microsoft COBOL alienating position-specifier `(x, y)`, their `LIN` and `COL` registers (must be explicit requested) and `DISPLAY ERASE`.
It actually compiles and runs the given sample perfectly fine :-)